# Question about proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^2 f(x) \sin(x^n)=0$ for any $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis

For $x \in [0, 1)$ we have $\sin(x^{n}) \to 0$ and we have $|f(x)\sin(x^{n})|\le |f(x)| \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ so by the LDCT $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\sin(x^{n})=0.$$

It is therefore sufficient to prove the integral is zero on $[1, 2]$.

The following claim is made about this integral: using the density of step-functions in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, it is enough to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_1^2 1_{[a, b]}\sin(x^{n})=0.$$

This seems easy enough to prove using integration by parts, but I'm wondering how exactly does the density of the step-functions give us the desired conclusion for any $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \in L^1$, then let $\varepsilon > 0$, and we can find $s(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \mathbf{1}_{[a_i,b_i]}$ such that $\int_1^2|f(x)-s(x)| < \varepsilon$ (as simple functions are dense in $L^1$). Then we have, by the triangle inequality:
$$
\left| \int_1^2 f(x)sin(x^n)dx \right| = 
\left| \int_1^2 (f(x)-s(x))sin(x^n)dx + \int_1^2 s(x)sin(x^n)dx \right| \leq 
$$
$$
\left|\int_1^2 (f(x)-s(x))sin(x^n)dx \right|+ \left| \int_1^2 s(x)sin(x^n)dx \right| \leq 
$$
$$
\int_1^2 |f(x)-s(x)|dx + \left| \int_1^2 s(x)sin(x^n)dx \right| \leq 
\varepsilon + \left| \int_1^2 s(x)sin(x^n)dx \right|
$$
(where the second inequality follows from $\sin(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$.

Using the result you developed, you can show that for sufficiently large $N$:
$$
\left| \int_1^2 s(x)sin(x^N)dx \right| < \varepsilon
$$
(To do this, just break up $s(x)$ into its summands then apply your result to each summand), this shows that for large enough $N$, you have:
$$
\left| \int_1^2 f(x)sin(x^N)dx \right| < 2 \varepsilon
$$
Which gives you the result you're looking for.

Comment: It's not $\vert f(x)-s(x)\vert <\varepsilon$, but $\int_1^2 \vert f(x)-s(x) \vert dx <\varepsilon$. The approximation is in $L^1$ and not in $L^\infty$ (otherwise it is not true, take Dirichlet's function to get a counterexample to uniform convergence). Your argument can be saved by also using $\vert \sin(x^n)\vert \leq 1$.

Comment: Yes, that's right -- I'll fix it. Accidentally omitted the $\int$

Comment: Thanks so much wflewis and @SeverinSchraven.

Comment: @wflewis When you drop the factor of $\sin(x^n)$ you probably want to put the absolute value inside the integral.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Fixed, thanks